# ctrl+c on login

Tags: bash, login

when I ssh using mobaXterm to a RHEL7 server (with uname and pwd saved) I just get a blinking cursor that will take input but not execute anything.  I can press `ctrl+c` and then appears `bash-4.2$` and all is well however this is annoying and adding `ctrl+c` to mobaXterm execute command on log in does not "solve" the issue here.

Using other ssh/telnet tools such as putty,secureFX yields same results (`ctrl+c` to get interactive shell)

Comment: Have you tried another program like PuTTY? Also you could check and see if there is something weird in your `.bash_profile`

Comment: @ZacharyBrady Yup, same behaviour through putty had to ctrl+c and then appeared bash...

Comment: Would you be able to post the contents of your `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @ZacharyBrady I don't have a `.bash_profile` I only have `.profile` which contains `SHELL='type -p bash' exec bash -l` single quotes are actually back ticks...

Comment: You should not have `exec bash -l` in your `.profile`! Having it there means that each `bash` login shell keeps restarting itself (and you can only login if you interrupt this endless cycle). If you want to ensure you have a Bash shell, replace that with `[ -n "$BASH" ] || exec bash -l` which only executes the Bash shell if `BASH` environment variable is undefined or empty. (Bash automatically sets it itself, so you only end up executing a Bash shell once.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `.profile` actually does contain:

```
SHELL=`type -p bash`
exec bash -l
```

And there is no `.bash_profile`, we have a loop. Your login shell (say `/bin/sh`, perhaps) reads `.profile`, which causes it to `exec` bash as a login shell. Bash, when run as a login shell, reads `.bash_profile`, and if that is missing, `.profile`. So, it too would read execute these commands, which causes it to `exec` bash as a login shell. Bash, when run as a login shell, ….

This might be a saner way to do this:

```
if [ -z "${BASH_VERSION}" ];
then
    SHELL=`type -p bash`
    exec bash -l
fi
```

Though, instead of hacks like this, you should ask your system administrator to set bash as your login shell (assuming you can't do so yourself using `chsh`).